# Array as a reference to other arrays

Tags: java

Is it possible to have an array containing names or reference to other arrays?

e.g.

```
String[] fruits={"orange","apple"};
String[] colors={"red","blue","green"};
```

And the 3rd array `String[] array1={"fruits","colors"};`

I actually have many arrays and based on the array passed I need to compare it with the array already present.

Like if I pass a `fruit` array then compare array1[0]th array i.e fruits array to the passed array?

I can compare the passed array to individual arrays and perform comparison for each but is there a shorter way?

Comment: Looks like your are looking for a `Map<String, String[]>`.

Comment: It would be `String[][] arrayOfArrays = {fruits, colors};` but as @jlordo said, a map would probably be a better fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like suggested in my comment below the question, you can use a map:

```
    String[] fruits = {"orange", "apple"};
    String[] colors = {"red", "blue", "green"};

    Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("fruits", fruits);
    map.put("colors", colors);

    String[] toCompare = map.get("fruits"); // will return the fruits array
```

Comment: Thanks jlordo! Just what i needed :) thank u every1 for the quick response :)

Answer (score 2):

You can have an array of arrays:

```
String[][] myArr = {fruits, colors};
```

But as @jlordo suggested, it's a better approach to have a [**Map**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that contains a `String` key which will represent the array's name, and the actual array as the *value*.

Answer (score 0):

Since double array has already been presented as well as a map example lets see an example with arraylist.

```
    String[] fruits = {"orange", "apple"};
    String[] colors = {"red", "blue", "green"};

    ArrayList<String[]> fruitsAndColors = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    fruitsAndColors.add(fruits);
    fruitsAndColors.add(colors);
```

You can read the java API for other insertion methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Yup! even this is correct.. But i needed a key value pair which is possible only if i use map.. But my question was ambiguous.. So i accept your answer as well :)

Comment: @Tanna: You can only accept one answer - therefore you have unaccpepted my answer ;)

Comment: Ya saw it.. Accepted yours :)

Comment: It's atleast plenty of options here ;) Gl with your coding =)

Answer (score -1):

You can have an array with references to almost anything using `Object` class (you are not limited to arrays of `String`):

```
Object [] myArr = {fruits, colors};
```

Comment: This is probably not very useful, you'd have to cast things everywhere.

Comment: Agree, but in the question the String array is only an example. As I understand it, String array is not a requirement.